# How to exclude multiple file extensions in typescript configuration?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Is it possible to use this kind of sintaxe or something similar to specify multiple extensions for exclude in **tsconfig.json**?

```
"exclude": [
  "**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
]
```

Comment: cant you add more than one entry? i mean after all it is an array. i would just try that

Comment: yeah @JonathanAlfaro I could do this: "exclude": [ "\*\*/\*.stories.?s", "\*\*/\*.stories.?sx" ]

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @Espi
No, I didn't. I had to get one line for each extension.

Comment: Are there `*.stories.*` files with extensions _other_ than `(js|jsx|ts|tsx)`? If not, you could do just `"exclude": [ "**/*.stories.*", ]`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

Glob patterns are not regular expressions. You need to specify them individually. For example:

```
"exclude": [
  "**/*.stories.js",
  "**/*.stories.jsx",
  "**/*.stories.ts",
  "**/*.stories.tsx",
]
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as the bounty award receiver.
I'll leave this link here, which shows some candidates for globbing extensions together just in case: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/node-js-how-to-include-multiple-file-extensions-with-glob-sync-in-nodejs/